# Newman Library - GET environment variables that are created during a collection run

Tags: javascript, node.js, newman

Is it possible to retrieve environment variables that are created in the collections requests when using Newman as a library and executing via Node.js?

Currently I have the following:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd6s7.png)

This works to some degree but the problem I have is that as my event trigger is set to 'request'. This means that all my const & variables are called each time a new request is run, which then causes a error on later requests as some requests do not have json as their response body so the var obj = JSON.parse(data.response.stream) won't work nor does it need to at that point. I could put these inside the function so they are only used at that point but do require certain things like the 'folderName' later on.

Error produced: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0

The best solution I could think of would be to use the environment variables that are set during the collection run. I already store QuoteId as one of these but am unable to retrieve it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. create one environment file, pass the env file name in the environment key. you can retrieve it at both runtime and after the execution.

if you are saving "QuoteId" in your env file.

at your runtime : pm.environment.get("QuoteId")
at your end execution : read json file and get your value.

[image]